# Mergesort for easy68k

Tags: assembly, 68000

has anybody done a merge sort in m68k?

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 1):

the third hit on google if you search for "mergesort 68k asm"

http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kma26/personal/downloads/

http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kma26/personal/downloads/MergeSort.x86 <--68k code inside..